# Object Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript

Using:

```
console.log("First Item Author: "+myjson.value.items.0.author);
```

I get the following error:

```
Object Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Trying to access the following object:

[image]

Comment: That's _Javascript_.  It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JSON either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0` is not a valid identifier and cannot be used as a direct property name.

Instead, use array notation:

```
items[0].author
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked like a charm, using just `myjson.value.items` I would be able to do a `foreach` correct?

Comment: @HydraIO: Javascript does not have a `foreach` loop, and `for in` should not be used to iterate arrays.   If you mean `.forEach()`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`0` is not a valid [identifier name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables). Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation):

```
console.log("First Item Author: " + myjson.value.items[0].author);
```